# How to save data in a table with multiple foreign keys while using a stored procedure in C# 

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I have a table `Item_Order` with the columns

```
orderId, clintName, companyName, itemName, orderDate, qauntity, clintId_FK, itemId_FK, status
```

where `clintId_FK` and `item_FK` are the primary keys of the `Clint` and `Item_Configuration` tables, respectively.

I have created a stored procedure for an insert record in the `Item_Order` table. i.e.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Order_Create_SP]
@orderId varchar(50),
@clintName varchar(50),
@companyName varchar(50),
@itemName  varchar(50),
@orderDate datetime,
@qauntity int,
@status char(10),
@operation int

AS
DECLARE @id1 varchar(50)
DECLARE @id2 varchar(50)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

if @operation = 0
BEGIN

SELECT top(1)@id1 = clintId FROM dbo.Clint order by clintId desc
select top(1)@id2 =  itemId from dbo.Item_Configuration order by itemId desc

insert into Item_Order(orderId, clintName, companyName, itemName, orderDate, qauntity, clintId_FK, itemId_FK, status)
 values(@orderId, @clintName, @companyName, @itemName, @orderDate, @qauntity, @id1, @id2, 'OPEN')

END
END
```

and my C# code is

```
private void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand inserOrder= new SqlCommand("Order_Create_SP", conn1);
            inserOrder.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@orderId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@orderId"].Value = oredrId.Text;

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@clintName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@clintName"].Value = comboClint.Text;

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@itemName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@itemName"].Value = comboItem.Text;

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@orderDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

          inserOrder.Parameters["@orderDate"].Value=Convert.ToDateTime(orderDate.Text);
          inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@qauntity", SqlDbType.Int);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@qauntity"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(qauntity.Text);

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@stauts", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@stauts"].Value = "OPEN";

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@companyName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@companyName"].Value = companyName.Text;

            inserOrder.Parameters.Add("@operation", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inserOrder.Parameters["@operation"].Value = 0;

            inserOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am doing something that is not compatible? It is not working properly. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a particular error message thats happening?

Comment: Please clarify `not working properly`.  Are you getting errors, unexpected behavior, an uneasy feeling?

Comment: Your c# code is not complete, can you complete it to see all the code of your button Click please. And can you give the error message you have to be more specific.

Comment: meessege is about SqlException and tds parser

Comment: where you open the connection ?

Comment: i have done all these thing open connection and all that i just post my logic here ,there is no problem regarding to connection trust me

Comment: Is it really a `clint` in your language, or is this just a mis-spelled `client` ? (BTW: `customer` would most likely be more appropriate here). Also: it's `quantity` (not `qauntity`) - and it's still a **stored** procedure (*stored* inside your database) - not a "store" proc ....

Comment: `messege is about SqlException and tds parser` - Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem or not, but your stored procedure is missing `WHERE` clauses when looking up the foreign keys.  Try changing to something like

```
SELECT top(1)@id1 = clintId FROM dbo.Clint WHERE Name = @clintName order by clintId desc
SELECT top(1)@id2 =  itemId from dbo.Item_Configuration WHERE name = @itemName order by itemId desc
```